# Insert different values from same column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

It may be a simple question, but I am really stuck at this.

I need something like this statement:

```
    INSERT INTO `DB`.`converted_values` (`type`,`old_value`, `new_value`)
            SELECT 'USER_ID',`users`.`id` AS _OLD , `users`.`id` as _NEW
            FROM `DB`.`users`
            WHERE _OLD IN ( SELECT `id` FROM `DB`.`users` WHERE `level`=ORIGINAL_LEVEL) 
            AND _NEW IN ( SELECT `id` FROM `DB`.`users` WHERE `level`=NEW_LEVEL);
```

The column `level` is NOT UNIQUE and may return N results, but the same number of rows for `_OLD` and `_NEW`.

The final result must be something like this:

```
type    | old_value | new_value
USER_ID | 8         | 500
USER_ID | 17        | 507
USER_ID | 60        | 521
USER_ID | 81        | 890
```

Thanks.

Comment: you trying to do trigger ?

Comment: Can you publish your user table description an sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Try don't using alias

```
      INSERT INTO `DB`.`converted_values` (`type`,`old_value`, `new_value`)
        SELECT  distinct 'USER_ID',`users`.`id`  , `users`.`id`  
        FROM `DB`.`users`
        WHERE `users`.`id`  IN ( SELECT `id` FROM `DB`.`users` WHERE `level`=ORIGINAL_LEVEL) 
        AND `users`.`id` IN ( SELECT `id` FROM `DB`.`users` WHERE `level`=NEW_LEVEL);
```

Comment: may i know this what is the need of (as) here ?

Comment: Thanks, but this does not help.
The alias was just for explaining purpose. When I run your suggestion, I get duplicated values for each column. I tried GROUP BY, but mysql complains about the Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: The as was a typo and for duplicate value (strange beacuse the alias removing don't change the query set )  use  distinct don't group by ... i have update the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
drop    table users;
CREATE TABLE users
(user_id VARCHAR(6),LEVEL VARCHAR(20), id INT);
truncate table users;
INSERT INTO users
VALUES
('USER-1','ORIGINAL' , 8),
('USER-2','ORIGINAL' , 17),
('USER-3','ORIGINAL' , 60),
('USER-4','ORIGINAL' , 61),
('USER-1','NEW' , 500),
('USER-2','NEW' , 507),
('USER-3','NEW' , 521),
('USER-1','NEW' , 600)
;
*/

select  u1.user_id,u1.id 'Old', u2.id 'New' 
from    users u1
join    users u2 on u2.user_id = u1.user_id
where   u1.id IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM users WHERE level = 'ORIGINAL' and user_id = u1.user_id)
    AND u2.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users WHERE level = 'NEW' and user_id = u2.user_id)
order   by u1.user_id
```